# Can I have two internal disks - one ext4 and one ntsf?

Tags: windows-7, ext4

Can I have two internal disks - one ext4 and one ntfs?  I am putting together a small home server with ubuntu desktop.  I also want to use it for windows 7 backups, so if I install a ntsf hdd as well as the primary ext4 hdd will it work? Meaning, will I be able to have access to the ntsf hd from within ubuntu to share it to the network?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer, yes you can.

You can mount an NTFS drive in Linux, but you won't be able to mount the drive directly in windows since windows cannot recognize the ext4 file system.

See [Mounting Windows Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions), also [The Ubuntu installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation), and finally [Install Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest)

Comment: Just to clarify the second sentence - "...you won't be able to mount the ext4 drive directly in Windows..."  Linux will let you access both disks.  Windows will only "see" the NTFS formatted disk.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your underlying question, you don't need ntfs; you can share files on any filesystem type over the network just as well.